# Cannot allocate memory on Popen commands

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi, popen

I have a VPS server with Ubuntu 11.10 64bit and sometimes when I execute a subprocess.Popen command I get am getting too much this error:

> OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Config details:
For each site I have an apache site like this: http://pastebin.com/mcew79sH
And also a settings and a wsgi file (both on same folder than project) like this: http://pastebin.com/hrrV4WTM

I am passing the arguments to Popen constructor as a list and using close_fds=True, I am also using and stdin/stdout to communicate with PIPE for the ones which I need reading the response.

Finally this is the traceback I get when the error appears http://pastebin.com/FqXPHwhq

The server is serving about 25 sites with small traffic (probably 5 of them has a considerable daily use) my VPS RAM size is 1024MB all of them execute PostgreSQL databases.

All this started when we migrated the sites from a VPS running Ubuntu Server 10.10 32 Bit to  11.10 64Bit.

Any idea how to solve this?

---- EDIT ----

ps aux --> http://synsa.synsa.com/site_media/process.txt

Comment: I thought 1024MB would be more than enough for less than 50 sites with not very high traffic, probably it is time to look for cheaper alternatives for apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's easy.  Sounds like it's time to upgrade your vps or scale back the memory settings of postgres/apache/etc and take the resulting performance hit.

Answer (score 1):

Some VPS providers calculate memory limits in strange ways. See if what is described in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Memory_Constrained_VPS_Systems

helps at all.

Comment: The main problem was that each site consume much more RAM that I have planned even if the site wasn't even visited.