# Resource leak when launching subprocesses with subprocess.call()

Tags: python, linux, git, python-2.7

I am writing a Python crawler to clone git repositories and analyze them. I am using subprocess.call() to clone a given repository. The problem is that after only a few repositories, I get a "OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory":

```
File "main.py", line 44, in main
     call(["git", "clone", remote_url.strip(), os.getcwd() + '/' + DIR_NAME])
File /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
     return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
     errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1222, in _execute_child
     self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
```

I tried using the sh module as well as GitPython. How can I avoid this problem?

My code is as follows:

```
for remote_url in remote_urls:
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(os.getcwd() + '/' + DIR_NAME):
            shutil.rmtree(os.getcwd() + '/' + DIR_NAME)
        os.mkdir(DIR_NAME)

        # repo_url = remote_url.replace('ssh://', '')
        call(["git", "clone", remote_url.strip(), os.getcwd() + '/' + DIR_NAME])

        # with sh.git.bake(_cwd=os.getcwd() + '/' + DIR_NAME) as git:
        #     git.clone(remote_url.strip())

        print 'Pulled # ' + str(repo_count) + ' repos'
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        continue
```

Comment: ```call()``` by itself isn't a builtin function (at least not in my version), is that supposed to be ```subprocess.call()``` or something else?

Comment: Yes, apologies. subprocess.call(). Edited post.

Comment: You have no problems running the `git clone` commands on the command line? Or check how much memory (roughly; e.g., run `top` in another window) each `git clone` command consumes.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111242/how-to-avoid-errno-12-cannot-allocate-memory-errors-caused-by-using-subprocess) and the other questions it links to.

Comment: Thanks Evert - yes, git clone works fine on the command line. The problem occurs after I have cloned around 10 repos...

Thanks dano - seen it already. To no avail...