Avoiding fork() memory issues when running external commands from a large Python process
I'm maintaining a memory-intensive Python application that occasionally needs to execute external commands (e.g., ls -l) and capture their output. The legacy code uses subprocess.Popen for this purpose. However, I've observed that sometimes the command execution fails, and I suspect it's because Popen uses fork() under the hood on Linux systems.
Since fork() duplicates the parent's memory space, when the parent process is large, I suspect this can lead to memory allocation failures—even if the child doesn't need all that memory.
To address this issue, I researched how to execute external commands without duplicating the entire parent process's memory while still capturing the command's output. I came up with two alternative methods that share the same run_command function signature and use the exact same main function for consistent comparison.
Method 1: Using multiprocessing with "spawn"
import multiprocessing  
   
def _internal_run_command(cmd):  
    import subprocess  
    process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)  
    output, _ = process.communicate()  
    return output  
   
def run_command(cmd):  
    multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn", force=True)  
    with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool:  
        result = pool.apply(_internal_run_command, (cmd,))  
    return result  

Method 2: Using os.posix_spawnp()
import os  
   
def run_command(cmd):  
    r, w = os.pipe()  
    try:  
        pid = os.posix_spawnp(  
            cmd[0],            # File to execute  
            cmd,               # argv  
            os.environ.copy(), # env  
            file_actions=[  
                (os.POSIX_SPAWN_DUP2, w, 1),  # Redirect stdout to write end of pipe  
                (os.POSIX_SPAWN_CLOSE, r),    # Close read end in child  
            ],  
        )  
        os.close(w)  # Close write end in parent  
  
        output = b""  
        while True:  
            chunk = os.read(r, 1024)  
            if not chunk:  
                break  
            output += chunk  
        os.close(r)  
  
        os.waitpid(pid, 0)  
        return output.decode()  
    except Exception as e:  
        print(e)  

Main Function (shared by both methods):
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    output = run_command(["ls", "-l"])  
    print(output)  

Comparison of Methods:



Aspect
Method 1: Multiprocessing with "spawn"
Method 2: Using os.posix_spawnp()




Cross-platform Compatibility
Yes (works on Linux, macOS, Windows)
No (POSIX only: Linux, macOS)


Implementation Complexity
Uses high-level modules (multiprocessing, subprocess); less manual code
Requires manual management of pipes and file descriptors


Performance
Overhead of starting a new Python interpreter
Efficient direct execution without extra overhead



My Concerns:
This is quite low-level infrastructure code that is manually implemented and might introduce unexpected issues. I'm concerned that by manually handling processes, pipes, and file descriptors, we're re-inventing the wheel for what seems to be a problem that we are not the first ones to encounter.
My Questions:

Is there a better way to execute external commands from a memory-intensive Python process on Linux that avoids fork() and allows me to capture the output?

For example, is there a way to use subprocess or another standard library module that doesn't rely on fork()?


Are there other pros and cons I should consider between these two methods?

If there aren't better alternatives, I'd like to understand more about the trade-offs involved.



Additional Information:

We're currently running on Linux systems, so POSIX-only solutions are acceptable.
The primary goal is to avoid memory allocation failures due to fork() duplicating the large memory space of the parent process.
Capturing the output of the external command is essential for our application's functionality.


Disclaimer:
I tried to figure out if it's against rules by reading meta questions but was not sure so I'm explicitly adding this section.

I used ChatGPT for generating the alternatives (but tested them before posting and they both alternatives).
I used ChatGPT to formalize the question, but all the details are precise after many iterations on the results.


AFAIK, fork, on linux, will provoke a "copy-on-write" of the process memory. So, in reality, for a classical fork/exec (what happens when you just fork to run ls -l) should not really be bothered by the memory used by the parent.

And just to be extra sure, I've tested. If I malloc an array the size of my remaining memory (2Gb. Small machine...), then fork 3 times, and in each subprocess, sleep 30 seconds (just to be sure that the effect of memory duplication is not annihilated magically so fast that it doesn't show), then do some exec, at no moment more memory than the initial 2Gb is gone. And I unfortunately know from (many) experience that my machine would have anyway crashed. So, I insist: fork uses copy-on-write. It doesn't really, even only temporarily, consume copy of parent memory.

Those are great inputs @chrslg. Indeed I emphasized we suspect and are not sure about the root cause. It doesn't reproduce on our end but it's consistently reproduce on our client's end so implementing any alternative would better help us be more certain about the root cause. Plus, exploring your input it seems like there might be still cases in which even with COW there might be allocation error (refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31039103/1157173). I'll ask our client to run cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory on the impacted machine.

Of course, if parent process changes content of large chunk of memory during the short interval between the fork and the exec, then, that would cause the "copy on write" to actually duplicate memory. But I take this is not the plan, if what you want to do is call some ls -l.

@Dorad You need to ask a single specific question. Anyway, research more. Both of your methods will call the fork() internally in Linux. What's important is not avoiding forking, but when to fork. You need to fork at the beginning of your main module, wait a command, then fork again for executing the command. You can easily do this by using the multiplrocessing library. See Customized managers.

_"I used ChatGPT to formalize the question" and that is not allowed.
